# I'm trying get data from server by id query but showing an empty array. there also console log not showing any error?

Tags: node.js, server, parameters, get, console.log

I'm trying get data from server by id query but it showing an empty array. There console log als not showing any error?

**my server site code**

```
    // get order for payment
    app.get('/myOrders/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: id }
        console.log(query)
        const result = orderCollection.findOne(query);
        res.json(result)
    })
```

this is my code I write for get order from my orderCollection and when i try to test by locally, browser show an empty array. url that I try in my browser is http://localhost:5000/myOrders/618feeccf38ede94d3d96e17

Another problem is **I try to the see the error in console but console also clear and no error showing.**

**my cmd terminal**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Time keeper new site, 5000
connected to time keeper
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. There is a mistake to the server code the correct code will be

```
    // get order for payment
    app.get('/payment/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: id }
        console.log(query)
        const result = await orderCollection.findOne(query);
        console.log(result)
        res.json(result)
    })
```

1. firstly in the get you will use

```
app.get('/payment/:id', async (req, res) => {
            
        })
```

2. secondly use **await** before the orderCollection();

```
const result = await orderCollection.findOne(query);
```